# Router issue in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am newbie in react. I am working on routing. I found that when I click on link, the URL change as per the link clicked, but it doesn't navigate to the next screen: https://jsfiddle.net/v78kncLb/

```
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Route,
    Link,
} from 'react-router-dom'
import Demo from "./demo";

<Router>
                <div className='input-form'>
                    <form>
                        <label>Name</label><br/>
                        <input type="text" name="username" onChange={this.onChange}
                               value={this.state.username}/><br/><br/>

                        <label>Password</label>
                        <input type="text" name="password" onChange={this.onChange}
                               value={this.state.password}/><br/><br/>

                        <label>Confirm Password</label>
                        <input type="text" name="confirm" onChange={this.onChange}
                               value={this.state.confirm}/><br/><br/>

                        <label>E-mail</label><br/>
                        <input type="text" name="email" onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.email}/><br/><br/>

                        <label>Aadhar</label><br/>
                        <input type="text" name="aadhar" onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.aadhar}/><br/><br/>

                        <label>Pan</label><br/>
                        <input type="text" name="pan" onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.pan}/><br/><br/>

                        <label>Voter</label><br/>

                        <Link to='./demo' className="btn btn-primary">hello</Link>
                        <Route exact path="/"/>
                        <Route path="./demo" component={Demo}/>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </Router>
```

Comment: You can learn from working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/6p2p1zzn and https://codesandbox.io/s/vVoQVk78

Comment: Have tried making sample its working absolutely fine but when i implemented in this its not working @Oleg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with you path. Update it by like below ( no dot before path)

```
<Link to='./demo' className="btn btn-primary">hello</Link>
<Route exact path="/"/>
<Route path="/demo" component={Demo}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put switch after Router like ;

```js
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

const App = () => {
  return(
    <Router>
      <div className='app'>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/"/>
          <Route path="/demo" component={Demo}/>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  )
}
```

Comment: Also you need to delete . before /demo

Answer (score 0):

Remove the dot '.' from the Route path and Link. Just use this
`<Route path="/demo" component={Demo}/>`

Comment: thanks ..it worked for me but text is appending in the ./App file..what should i do for that??

Thanks a lot..@Md Isfar Uddin AINur

Comment: Sorry did not understand. Could you explain it a little bit more?